# Android Retrofit okhttp error

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Retrofit and okhttp to do network requests in my app. While trying to make login request, I see that when it is a fresh install, it works fine. I get a 200 response but when I try to log out and log back in, I get this exception in the logs.Has anyone see such an issue. Please help.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cache is closed
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.checkNotClosed(DiskLruCache.java:630)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.get(DiskLruCache.java:424)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.get(Cache.java:184)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache$1.get(Cache.java:139)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:226)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
D/Retrofit:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
D/Retrofit:     at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
D/Retrofit:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
D/Retrofit:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
D/Retrofit:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
D/Retrofit:     at $Proxy3.storeList(Unknown Source)
```

I resolved this bug. I was not setting this "ref" to null when I log out and close the disk. Hence when I log back in, it caused the exception.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson()))
            .setExecutors(newAsyncExecutor(), useAsyncCallbacks ? newAsyncExecutor() : newMainThreadExecutor())
            .setClient(getRetrofitClient())
            .setEndpoint(serverUrl)
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
                    requestFacade.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                }
            });
MyClass ref = restAdapter.create(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Don't call `close()` on your disk cache.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/689) will be helpful for you. Moreover, please post your code for more information, only logcat info, IMO, is not enough :)

Comment: Please post your code, just this information will not be enough to help you

Comment: please post your code so we can know where you have faced exception

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem with `DiskLruCache` class:

```
  /** Returns true if this cache has been closed. */
  public synchronized boolean isClosed() {
    return closed;
  }

  private synchronized void checkNotClosed() {
    if (isClosed()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("cache is closed");
    }
  }
```

So I think, to better give you an answer on **how** to handle the situation that give you that errors, you should post the piece of code where you get this error.

Comment: I resolved this bug. I have given the explanation above.